# PostgreSQL's PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT log security

Tags: postgresql, security, encryption, log

In one of our project, I tried to use PostgreSQL's security extension `pgcrypto`. I found that is function, `PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT` is quite handy. Using this function enable me to query encrypted data with `LIKE %keyword%`, `BETWEEN` etc, which I can not achieve if I use programming language such as Java or PHP to encrypt the data then insert it into the database.

However, I found an issue. Once I execute queries with `PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT` new line in the log file is written. Interestingly, the log is including the password in PLAIN!

Of course, IMO, this is unacceptable. I want to secure my `password`, in the same time I also want to log any change (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) into my database.

Is there any way to **hide** this password information from the log file?

Comment: If you enabled to log all statements, then all statements will be logged exactly as you sent them to the database. The logging system does not know anything about security critical values in a function call (or other SQL statements) and does not parse the statements. A statement like `select * from foo where col = foobar('bla', 'secret')` is no different at that level than `select * from foo where col = pgp_sym_encrypt('bla', 'secret')`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your configuration settings to make this *less likely* to occur (What setting was triggering the log message in the first place?)

But in general, if you send your password to the database, then the database has your password. There is simply no way around this, other than not sending your password to the database and dealing with the consequences of that.  If you do send your password to the database, then you must guard the database log files with the same vigilance as you guard the rest of the database.